# Launching new activity resets ViewPager

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with each view being a `WebView`.  In the `Actionbar` I have a menu item, where the user can open the web page in their default browser using this code:

```
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mUrl)));
```

However, if a user clicks on a link in the `WebView`, then opens the site in their default browser, then goes back to my app, they are shown the original web page, not the page they clicked to.  I thought about using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`, but that would only work if I opened a new activity in my own app, right?

This is the code for my `ViewPager`:

**Fragment**

```
public class Browser extends SherlockFragment {
    private String mUrl;    


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        activity = getActivity();

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mUrl = GetUrl();

        mWebView = (WebView)getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }

             @Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                  view.loadUrl(url);

                 return true;
             }            
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) 
    {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.open) {
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mUrl)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**Activity**

```
public class BrowserPager extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements Interfaces.OnBrowserSetTitle {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.browser_pager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot.  I was resetting the `ViewPager` in `onResume` of the `Activity`, which was causing the webpage to reset.  Moving the code to reset the `ViewPager` to `onCreate` fixed my issue.